# SQL Delete Duplicates with greater difference between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, subtraction

I have a table something similar to :

```
ID    Value1      Value2
122   800         1600
122   800         1800
133   700         1500
154   800         1800
133   700         1500
188   700         1400
176   900         1500
```

From this table I want to delete the duplicates (`ID` of `122` and `133`) which have a greater difference between value2 and value1.

This means that where `ID` is `122` I want to keep the first row (`1800-800>1600-800`)
This means that where `ID` is `133` I want to keep either one because they both have the same difference.

```
ID    Value1      Value2
122   800         1600
122   800         1800  <------delete this row
133   700         1500  <------delete either this row or the other identical row
154   800         1800
133   700         1500  <------delete either this row or the other identical row
188   700         1400
176   900         1500
```

It is on a much larger scale that this, so I cant just individually delete records.

Is there a way to write a statement that will delete all duplicates from my table where `Value2 - Value1` is greater than `Value2 - Value1` for its duplicate?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server or MySQL.  Please tag questions appropriately.

Comment: You can do something like that with a Stored Procedure...i think it's the best way IMHO

Comment: If your database is MS SQL Server, you could use a CTE. Help us help you by tagging your question with the correct database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has this great feature of updatable CTEs and subqueries.  So, you can do this as:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by value2 - value1) as diff_seqnum
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where diff_seqnum > 1;
```

That is, enumerate the rows for each id based on the difference in the two values.  Then, only keep the rows where the sequence number is `1`.